# Can Node.js "built-in" streams emit multiple errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I get a [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) or [`stream.Writable`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), for example after calling [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage), [`fs.ReadStream`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream) or [`fs.WriteStream`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream), should I assume that *all* events may fire multiple times, unless the documentation says otherwise?

I'm especially interested in the answer to these questions:

1. Can an `error` event fire multiple times?
2. If an `error` event is emitted, what other events can still happen? (e.g. `data`?)

The questions assume:

- The `error` event is caught and doesn't throw.
- No third-party libraries are used.

## Code samples

```
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  host: 'localhost',
  path: '/',
};

require('http').get(options, function(response) {
  // ...

  response.on('end', callback);
  response.on('error', callback);

  // ...
});

function callback() {
  // Can this function be called multiple times?
}
```

---

```
var s = require('fs').createReadStream('/path/to/file');

s.on('end', callback);
s.on('error', callback);

function callback() {
  // Can this function be called multiple times?
}
```

---

```
var s = require('fs').createWriteStream('/path/to/file');

s.on('finish', callback);
s.on('error', callback);

function callback() {
  // Can this function be called multiple times?
}
```

Comment: I guess "*should I assume […] unless the documentation says otherwise?*" can generally be answered with a *YES* :-) Especially in case of custom or subclassed streams.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I currently code like "they didn't say no, which means it can happen" (better safe than sorry). I asked mostly out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Yyyeeesss.

Just kidding... As documentation says, `The stream is not closed when the 'error' event is emitted`, so yes, as the stream is actually open after receiving an error, everything else can still happen. So after receiving an error, you are still going to receive the `finish` or `end` or `whatever` event it can throw.

Usually the `end` event is called after an error, as, usually, the error is about not being able to read/write more data and such, but don't assume this as a rule as your program needs to be prepared for every situation.

If you want your program stop reading/writting after an error 100% of the times, you must call `.end()` to make sure that end happens.

Comment: Heh, +1 for the "long answer". In my defense, I was reading the docs for `4.x` (LTS), and that message seems to have been added in `6.x` (Current). Next time I'll check both versions before asking.

Comment: @noisypixy Oh, that makes sense. I was curious about you didn't noticed the note in the docs xD